# Java Scanner Reading Leading Space

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to have a menu that takes a character input for a switch case and loops till the input is q but after the loop run once i get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source) at Menu.main(Menu.java:19)

Which means its getting a null input right? So i added the .trim() but i still get the error, it doesn't even wait for an input i just get the error.

Sorry if this has been answered before but i can't find it anywhere. I've also tried adding keyboard.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?"); which doesn't work as well.

**Input given for the program with error log:**

```
Enter Option (a,b,c,d,e,f,q):

c

Enter 2 Numbers

First Number:

1

Second Number:

10

1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Enter Option (a,b,c,d,e,f,q):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at Menu.main(Menu.java:19)
```

**CODE:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    char ch; int m,n; String y;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Option (a,b,c,d,e,f,q):");
        ch = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'c':
            
            System.out.println("Enter 2 Numbers");
            System.out.println("First Number: ");
            m = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Second Number: ");
            n = keyboard.nextInt(); 
            for(int i = 1; i <= n - m + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    if (i != n - m + 1)
                    {
                    System.out.println(", ");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    if (i != n - m + 1)
                    {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                    }
                }
                
            }
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        }
    }while (ch != 'q');

}
 
}
```

Comment: I didn't get any error...it takes input if 1 character

Comment: working fine for me too.

Comment: What is the input you enter?

Comment: I updated the code to explain it better

Comment: If your error happens where you point it, added code doesn't make any sense, because it's after that line. The only reason you might be getting this exception is that you just hit enter and aren't entering any character as input.

Comment: Provide switch case code of option c: .That is where the issue is.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is incomplete, it does not compile, has missing variables (m, n) and is poorly structured in the question.

Comment: Now, the question has a reproducible code to replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try the line** ch = keyboard.next().charAt(0); switch(ch)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    char ch; int m,n; String y;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Option (a,b,c,d,e,f,q):");
        ch = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'c':
            
            System.out.println("Enter 2 Numbers");
            System.out.println("First Number: ");
            m = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Second Number: ");
            n = keyboard.nextInt(); 
            for(int i = 1; i <= n - m + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    if (i != n - m + 1)
                    {
                    System.out.println(", ");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    if (i != n - m + 1)
                    {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                    }
                }
                
            }
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        }
    }while (ch != 'q');

}
 
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated code Please check:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    char ch;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Option (a,b,c,d,e,f,q):");
        ch = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);   
        switch (ch)
        {
        //case statements for a,b,c,d,e and f
        }
    }while (ch != 'q');

}
```

Comment: Same here: this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please check again...I have changed according his requirement

Answer (score 1):

Main thing here that scanner works with input right just after you hit "enter".
So if your input would be entering `'\u0020'`(whitespaces) even several times on line 19 you're doing trim to empty line and according to javadoc `charAt`.

[image]